# Making a to-do webapp and got such an error SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tasks.list_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Showing /home/arthur/Desktop/application/todo/app/views/tasks/index.html.erb where line #7 raised:SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tasks.list_id

This error appears when I am trying to open the created list to add new tasks. I think the problem is the app can't get the id of the list I am trying to open. But I can't understand what's wrong. (new with ruby and rails). Do I need to add views or something else?
Task Controller

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :task, :list, :tasks

  def create
    task.save

    redirect_to list_tasks_path(list)
  end

  def update
    task.update task_params

    redirect_to list_tasks_path(list)
  end

  def complete
    task.complete

    redirect_to list_tasks_path(list)
  end

  def destroy
    task.destroy

    redirect_to list_tasks_path(list)
  end

  private 

  delegate :tasks, to: :list, private: true

  def task 
    @task ||= params[:id] ? list.tasks.find(params[:id]) : list.tasks.new(task_params)
  end

  def list
    @list ||= List.find params[:list_id]
  end

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :completed)
  end
end
```

and ListsController

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  #helper_method :list, :lists
  def index
    @lists = List.order('created_at')
  end 

  def new
    @list = List.new
  end

  def create
    @list = List.new list_params

    @list.save

    redirect_to lists_path
  end

  def edit
    @list = List.find params[:id]

    redirect_to lists_path
  end

  def update
    @list = List.find params[:id]

    @list.update list_params

    redirect_to lists_path
  end

  def destroy
    @list = List.find params[:id]

    @list.destroy

    redirect_to lists_path
  end

  private

  def list_params 
    params.require(:list).permit(:title)
  end

end
```

View Index.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>Tasks</h2>

    <div class="buffer-top"><%= link_to "New Task", new_list_task_path(list), class: 'btn btn-primary' %></div>

    <div class="buffer-top">
        <% tasks.each do |task| %>  <----------- this line
            <%= render partial: 'task', object: task %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="buffer-top"><%= link_to "Back to Lists", lists_path, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %></div>

</div>
```

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord  
    belongs_to :lists

    def complete!
        self.completed = true
        save
    end
end

class List < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :tasks

end
```

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_04_06_202846) do

  create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.boolean "completed"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: What do your `Task` and `List` models look like? Hopefully, your `List` model has a `has_many :tasks`. Otherwise, Rails won't know that a list item has a `task_id`.

Comment: i've added my models

Comment: Which line is line 7 in your `index.html.erb`?

Comment: beginning of do-end block,  <% tasks.each do |task| %>

Comment: Hmm. That's line 7 in what you are showing but you're missing lines at the beginning (like opening `<div>`) so are you sure that's line 7 of the actual file?

Comment: tasks should be an array of every task created at list

Comment: Ok, that's what `tasks` should be. Can you show how you set it? Also, check my question above about "line 7".

Comment: Did you correctly run migrations? How does your schema.rb look like?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but I could miss something. I have added a schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `belongs_to :lists` in your Task model but no `list_id` in your corresponding `tasks` table. Your tasks table needs a migration with `t.integer "list_id", :null => false` in it.

```
  create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "list_id", :null => false
    t.string "title"
    t.boolean "completed"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```